# HSLab: null audio device

Tags: macos, audio, macos-sierra, htk

I'm a beginner of HTK (Hidden Markov Model Toolkit).
I just compiled and installed it on my Mac machine (MacOS Sierra).
When I run a HSLab command like:

`HSLab no_name`

it opens a GUI window properly. But when I click "rec" it crashes with:

`ERROR [+6015]  StartAudioInput: null audio device
FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HSLab`

The HTK version is 3.4.1 (current stable).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can produce the same error on my Linux machine (openSUSE Leap 42.2) running Pulseaudio sound manager. The fix for me is to prefix the command with `padsp` as in:

`padsp HSLab no_name`

Then the rec button works correctly. I'm not sure the audio recorded is what is required, but that is another issue. No doubt one day we will be able to compile HTK to be PA aware.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't install padsp on my mac. Maybe mac doesn't support padsp thing. Do you know any other alternatives?

Comment: @hiroki.n Sorry, not a Mac user. padsp is a wrapper around the application which restores access to legacy output audio devices, so perhaps there is a Mac wrapper which performs the same function?